# why a number e.g. 2 % a empty set greater than zero is true?

Tags: python, set

Can someone tell why the following result is true. 
all(2%p>0 for p in set())
I know that am empty set is false. I cannot understand why the remain after divided by a empty set is greater than zero.

Comment: Documentation for `all`: `Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty).`. If the set is empty, the created iterable won't have any elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) returns `True` if it's applied on an empty iterable. `set()` creates a new empty set, so calling `all` on any permutation on it, will return `True`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very helpful.